# Connecting to Novell Groupwise using BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, groupwise

I need to read incoming emails from Novell Groupwise using the BizTalk 2010 POP3 adapter.  No matter which combination of settings I try, I cannot log on to the POP3 server.  The Groupwise server responds to telnet on the 110 port, so there is a service listening.  The BizTalk server does not have the Groupwise client installed.  Is it in fact possible to talk to Groupwise without the client?

Is anyone aware of an email client I can use to try and connect to Groupwise?

Answer (score 1):

As long as POP3 is enabled in the GWIA (GroupWise Internet Agent) you should be able to use any POP3 client to connect to GroupWise.  Since you can telnet to port 110, and I assume you are telnetting to the IP address of the server running GWIA, then it sounds like POP3 is enabled.  Try using something like Thunderbird to see if you can connect.  Also make sure you're using the correct credentials.  Basically, whatever credentials you would use in the GW client or GW WebAccess should work with any POP3 client.